# Erro ao executar métodos de uma classe em cascata

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
1.  $customer = new Customer($apiContext);
2.  $customer->setVat('XYZ0123456')
3.           ->setName('Filipe')
4.           ->setLanguageId(1);
5.  (...)
```

O seguinte erro ocorre na linha 3:

> Call to a member function setName() on a non-object

Não é possível chamar métodos de uma mesma classe em cascata como demonstrado acima?

Comment: O retorno é `$this`?

Comment: Poste o código do `setVat` que veremos o problema

Comment: @Lucas tens razão, faltou o "return $this" dentro do método setName(). Obrigado.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para que possas criar ["method chaining"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), os teus métodos precisam de retonar `$this`, ou seja:

```
class Customer {
    function setVat() {
      echo "bubu!";
      return $this;
    }

    function setName() {
       echo "Bubu2!";
       return $this;
    }
}
```

E depois já podes:

```
$Customer = new Customer;
$Customer->setVat()->setName();
```

Comment: Mas é certo que aquele erro é gerado pela falta do `return $this;`?

Comment: @JorgeB. Sim, porque estás a chamar um método de algo que não é um objeto. Ao devolver o `$this` já passa a ser um objeto e o método já é localizado. (Essencialmente é o que o próprio erro nos diz) :)

Comment: Eu só queria saber se aquele erro só pode indicar este comportamento. Não há mais nenhum comportamento que possa levar a aquele erro?

Comment: @JorgeB. Aquele é o erro apresentado quando tentas aceder a uma variável assumindo que a mesma é um objeto. Quer por _chaining_ quer de forma regular: `$nome = $bubu->getName();` <- Vai dar o mesmo erro porque não fiz `$bubu = new bubu;` antes. Mas com essa dúvida, podes colocar uma pergunta nova e verás essa questão mais bem respondida ;)

Comment: Ah é que achei estranho terem a resposta pronta, sem verem a classe `Customer`.

Comment: @JorgeB. São problemas +/- comuns, e quem já passou por eles tem a resposta pronta ;)

Answer (score 7):

Para executar o código dessa forma (*Method Chaining*) é preciso que a sua classe `Customer` implemente um padrão chamado [*Fluent Interface<sup><sup>en</sup></sup>*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

Para conseguir fazer isso no PHP é preciso que os métodos da sua classe a serem encadeados retornem a instancia dela mesma (`$this`).

Sua classe ficará parecida com isso:

```
<?php

class Customer {

    public function setVat($vat){
        // ....     
        return $this;
    }

    public function setName($name){
        // ...      
        return $this;
    }

    public function setLanguageId($languageId){
        // ...      
        return $this;
    }

    // ...

}
```

Outra forma de fazer isso com PHP é utilizando o método mágico `__call()` em conjunto com setters privados.

```
<?php

class Customer {

    private function setVat($vat){
        // ....     
    }

    private function setName($name){
        // ...      
    }

    public function __call($name, $arguments){
        if (method_exists($this, $name) && strpos($name, 'set') === 0) 
        {
            $this->$name($arguments[0]);   // Tratar o número de argumentos passados é 
                                           // uma boa ideia

            //$this->$name(...$arguments); // A partir do PHP 5.6
            return $this;
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception('Invalid setter method');
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Os métodos públicos da classe seriam acessados perfeitamente, somente os setters que são privados e não estão expostos fora das classes que entrariam no `__call()`. Obrigando todos os setters a passarem pelo `__call()` não precisamos definir o retorno do `$this` em todos os métodos.

O `strpos($name, 'set') === 0` protege os métodos privados da nossa classe que não começam com `set`, impedindo assim o acesso indevido dos métodos privados da classe.

Comment: Esta deveria ser a resposta aceite, está mais detalhada e foi colocada primeiro!

Comment: Coloquei mais um exemplo, mostrando umas coisinhas a mais que dá pra fazer com o PHP :)

Comment: +1 por teres ido mais além... :)

Comment: @Zuul a resposta está mais completa sim, mas a sua está mais direta, pelo menos quando procuro por respostas no stackoverflow tento ir as respostas mais diretas. Isso não invalida a reposta do gmsantos, até apresentou outras possibilidades e mereceu +1 (além disso agradeço o tempo dispensado) e com certeza vai ajudar outros.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes Grato pela atenção :)